# Where to ask logic questions: not math logic but common real world problems

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I wanted to know answers to questions something like:

> "A man wants to take his wolf and two sheep across the river using a boat in such a way that he can take only one animal while travelling on the boat from one side to another side. Wolf eats sheep in the absence of the man. What does man do without wolf causing any harm?"

Where can I ask these kind of questions please?

Comment: To me, that sounds like something that would be asked at [Puzzling.SE]. But I would check what's acceptable there first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest SE site I see you can go to is

[SE Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/)

Be sure that your question meets [this site's policies](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) though 1st please.

---

Also note that I won't consider your example a *"common real world logic problem"*<sup>1</sup>, that stuff is already well known and purely hypothetical.

Your example question probably would get downvoted and closed as duplicate at that site. Here's one (duplicate) example I found quite quickly:

[When do missionaries and cannibals problems have solutions?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/55154/when-do-missionaries-and-cannibals-problems-have-solutions/55203#55203)

I think the answers show the principle how to solve that problem quite well.

I'd say you'll need to flesh out the *"real world context"* more to ask there.

---

<sup>1)</sup><sub>Note that any kind of *logical problems* can be reduced to more or less simple math, unless they can't be identified as [NP problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP_(complexity))</sub>

Comment: very few puzzling questions are real-world. The problem with the wolf/sheep problem is not it's artificiality (take a look at puzzling's `liars` tag) but that even a cursory search would find duplicates. Logic problems that are not just math are on topic on puzzling.

Comment: @Kate Sure. I just wanted to make a clarification regarding the NP problems always can be reduced to math. I didn't say the non NP problems are _off-topic_ at that site. I even don't have any experience about it :-D.

Answer (score 0):

[Philosophy.SE](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) lists these questions as on-topic:

> We welcome questions involving subjects like:
>
> - epistemology — the nature of knowledge and learning
> - ethics — the nature of the right thing to do
> - metaphysics — the nature of being and reality
> - **logic** — the nature of reasoning and inference
> - aesthetics — the nature of feelings and artistic sentiment
> - history of philosophy — the domains and personalities in the past associated with philosophy
> - applied philosophy — the more specific disciplines where philosophical methods are applied, such as **logic and argumentation**, the philosophy of language, political and social philosophy, psychoanalysis, theology, economics, the philosophy of science and mathematics, etc.

There are [2,401 questions](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic) tagged "**logic**", and [327 questions](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/argumentation) tagged "**argumentation**"; along with other related tags such as: [modal-logic](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modal-logic) on Philosophy.SE.

[Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22word+problems%22) does have 252 results for the search term "word problems". [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group-theory?tab=Newest) has 33,836 and [Mathoverflow.net](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/gr.group-theory) has 5,664 questions dealing with gr.group-theory (abstract algebra that deals with groups).

Where to ask depends upon whether your question is hypothetical, abstract or absolute.

"[River crossing problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/River_crossing_puzzle)" in particular are solved using [graph theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory) which has 16,240 questions, [dynamic programming](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-programming) which has 362 questions, [integer programming](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer-programming) which has 687 questions, or even [combinatorics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics) with 38,693 questions on Math.SE.